# Calling methods on CComBSTR variable in VS2015 debugger

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Quick question:

Is there a way to call, say the CComBSTR::Length() method on a local CComBSTR variable while debugging?
In either the Watch window or the Intermediate window?
Whenever I try, I just get

```
error: 'variableName.Length' does not exist
```

Comment: Length() is a function call, compiling one requires a C++ compiler and the debugger does not have one built-in.  You can put the m_str member in the Memory window, the four bytes before the string store the length in bytes.  Or type `*(int*)(var.m_str-2) / 2` in the watch.

Comment: Neat. Thanks Hans. 
I didn't know that the four bytes before the string store the length in bytes.

Is it not possible to call functions on native objects in memory in VS2015 debugger, like you can with gdb on a program compiled with g++?